# Help with Trigger to that will index Account Number field

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an urgent requirement as follows:

--Whenever the Opportunity Probability is moved to 80%, an Integer should be added to the AccountNumber field on the Account object. There is a lookup relationship between the Opportunity(child) and Account(parent) object.

--The Account number will never be changed by the Trigger; only set once if the AccountNumber field is NULL when the Opportunity Probability gets to 80%.

--The trigger will find the highest number in the appropriate number range and assign a number one higher.

--The number assigned by the trigger will depend on the type of Account(Partner or User) & the region of the Account (Americas or Offshore). as follows:

```
 If Account = Partner & Region = Americas assign a number between 3000-3999
 If Account = Partner & Region = Offshore assign a number between 9000-9999
 If Account = User & Region = Americas assign a number between 1000-1999
   If Account = User & Region = Offshore assign a number between 8000-8999
```

Here is what I have so far but i'm stuck with the logic:

```
 trigger AssignAccountNumber on Opportunity (after insert, after update){
 list<opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new list<opportunity>();
  for (Opportunity p:Trigger.new){
    if ((p.Probability >= 80)&&(p.accountnumber==null)){
       //your processing for pre-defined range, and update p
     oppsToUpdate.add(p);
     }
   }
   if(oppsToUpdate.size()>0)update oppsToUpdate;
  }
```

Any direction will be appreciated

Comment: Your first loop should just gather a set of Opportunity.AccountId values. You can then use that to query the Accounts (into a map keyed by the Account Id), then do your number calculations and finally update the Accounts that you queries.

Comment: Thanks Keith C for the direction! Could you post an example of code that would process the predefined range e.g assigning a number between 1000-1999?

Answer (score 2):

The assigning numbers part is awkward if you want to avoid duplicates when simultaneous requests are made.

One way to accomplish that is to use [for update](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm). Let me caution you that I have never written code that uses this so the code below is based on what I read in the documentation not real experience.

The idea is to dedicate a single row of a custom SObject (that you'll also have to be careful to insert to start with) and ensure that only one request can update it; other requests suffer a `QueryException` while the "for update" lock is on:

```
Number__c n;
Boolean ok;
do {
    try {
        ok = true;
        n = [
                select Ones__c, Threes__c, Eights__c, Nines__c
                from Number__c
                limit 1
                for update
                ];
        if (...) {
            n.Ones__c = n.Ones__c + 1;
        } else if (...) {
            n.Threes__c = n.Threes__c + 1;
        } else if (...) {
            n.Eights__c = n.Eights__c + 1;
        } else if (...) {
            n.Nines__c = n.Nines__c + 1;
        }
        update n;
    } catch (QueryException e) {
        ok = false;
    }
} while (!ok);

... use the appropriate n field value e.g. n.Ones__c
```

Another way would be to define 4 custom objects with an auto-number field on each (that is set to start at the correct number). You can then allocate a number like this:

```
Ones__c ones = new Ones__c();
insert ones;
Integer number = [select AutoNumber__c from Ones__c where id = :ones.Id];
delete ones;
Database.emptyRecycleBin(ones);
```

Another way if you don't mind the occasional duplicate you could use an [aggregate query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) and find the current max value and use one more than that. That would be simpler.

Comment: Instead of a custom object though, I'd suggest a custom setting.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yeah meant to mention that I wasn't sure about "for update" on those. I Googled for number allocators for Salesforce but didn't find a hit - presume there are some good posts somewhere on the subject with code that is proven to work...

Comment: Thank you! Let me try this out. I'll post the final trigger once I'm done.

Comment: I'm trying to use a custom setting. Should I use a single custom setting with 4 custom number fields, or 4 separate custom settings each with a dedicated custom number field? Also, autonumber is not available in custom settings.

Comment: @user8556 If "for update" does work with custom settings then you will need 4 fields to track the 4 sequences.

Comment: trigger AssignAccountNumber on Opportunity (before insert, before update){
   for (Opportunity o:Trigger.new){
     if ((o.Probability >= 95)&&(o.Account.AccountNumber==null)){
        accIndexx__c n;
        Boolean ok;
        do {
        try {
        ok = true;
        n = [SELECT Ones__c from accIndexx__c limit 1 for update];
        if (o.LC_Region__c=='Americas') {
            n.Ones__c = n.Ones__c + 1;
        }
        update n;
         } catch (QueryException e) {
        ok = false;
       }
       } while (!ok);
}
     }
   }