# Bulkifying class so it will update multiple records

Tags: apex, bulkification

ive got some code ive created which i need to update multiple different records with a unique service_id__c, currently the way we do is through a query but we need a create its own class and it sometimes still causes duplicates.

```
public static String generateServiceID(){
    Savepoint savePoint = Database.setSavepoint();
    String serviceID = 'AQ';
    for(Service_ID__c serviceIdObject : [SELECT Name, Service_ID_Value__c FROM Service_ID__c LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE]){
        Decimal nextRefNumber = serviceIdObject.Service_ID_Value__c;
        nextRefNumber++;
        serviceID += nextRefNumber;
        serviceIdObject.Service_ID_Value__c = nextRefNumber;
        update serviceIdObject;
    }

    return serviceID;
}

public string getServiceID(){

    return generateServiceID();

}
```

}

However in its current format, the button will cause it to error out because its trying to give for example 3 orders the same service_id__c any ideas would be gratefully appreciated..

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, some related discussion [High frequent sequential generated unique autonumber](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55481/high-frequent-sequential-generated-unique-autonumber).

Comment: yeah were trying to avoid SOQL locking in case when we develop this further it causes problems

Comment: I see you have "for update" in the code you posted. Locking appears to be the only way to avoid duplicates. That is unless you don't mind the gaps that can occur in auto-number fields.